# Sql Server - DB Diagram with additional requirements

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am generating Database diagram from Sql server 2005 Professional edition.

### Clinet is coming with some Strange Requirements as :

1 ) DB Diagarm should show the tables with constraints,referred SP,referred UDF , Triggers.

( any utility available to do so ? won't it mess up the real DB meaning ? ).

2 ) The client needs the separate diagram to diagramatically explain the execution of SP.(strange , Do i need to draw state diagram with Use cases ? ).

I request you to help me,how to handle the tasks mentioned above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import the datamodel into Visio and then mark up the diagram however you need to satisfy your client.